# checkbox value transfer to textbox separated by comma

Tags: ajax

i used this code to get the value of item that i checked however. its not working on my project. i just want every value that i checked it will go to my text box with comma separator
like 288,289,290. thanks in advance

```
<input type="text" name="holder" id="holder"
    <input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="288" checked/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="289" checked/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="290" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="example1[]" value="289" checked/>

    var output = jQuery.map($(':checkbox[name="example[]"]:checked'), function (n, i) {
        return n.value;
    }).join(',');

    alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="inputs">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Orange">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mango">
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="target"/>
</body>
</html>
var arr = [];
$('#inputs input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    arr.push(this.value);
  }
  else {
   arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
  }
  $('#target').val(arr + '');
});
```